# Cannot clear back stack with NEW_TASK and CLEAR_TASK on API > 15

Tags: android, android-intent, stack

**EDIT solution:** For some reason I launched activity 2 and 3 with the NEW_TASK flags as well.. So now it works with the code below.

**ORIGINAL question:**
I have searched and found multiple answer on how to clear back stack completely, but after trying multiple different solutions, I am still struggling. To clarify my problem, I have 3 activities where Activity 1 is the main activity, and at anytime the user can click the up button in the toolbar in activity 2 or 3 to go back to activity 1. At that point, the stack should be completely cleared and "start at scratch" with Activity 1. Activity 2 can also have multiple versions on the back stack. So for example:

1 > 2 > 2 > 3 (click up button) 1

or

1 > 2 > 2 > 2 (click up button) 1

All the answers I have found is basically saying the same thing, which is to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK when launching activity 1. Some also pointed out the use of `finish()` after starting the activity. So my code now looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.action_homepage:
            openHomepage();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

When clicking the up button I return to activity 1 as expected. However, when clicking the back button I return back to activity 2. In other words, the stack was not cleared.

This is implemented in a custom `BaseActivity` which activity 1, 2 and 3 all extends. However the up button is turned off in activity 1 as it is the "starting point". I have also tried adding `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to the manifest file, and using the CLEAR_TOP flag, as well as combining these.

Any idea why this does not work for me? Does acitivity 2 and 3 need to have certain flags for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can Override **OnBackPressed** method in your Activity 2 and 3.
Then call **finishAffinity()** which clears all back stack and then start your MainActivity.

For example,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finishAffinity();
    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
}
```

The above method will only work in **API 16 or above** as finishAffinity() method was added in API 16, so for lower versions, you can implement like below-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: This would apply for the **back button**, not the **up button**. Adding this to activity 2 and 3 makes it so I cannot go back when browsing activity 2. Or from activity 3 back to 2. And adding the `finishAffinity(); and `startActivity()` bits in the onOptionsItemSelected for the home button does not make a difference, it gives the same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using addFlags() method, you should try using setFlags() method. It works for me

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    startActivity(intent);
```